# Create a Address Book script with shell

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make an address book with unix shell but I have problem with the edit of fields. The fields are name;number;mail. This is my code, **i want to edit for example the name, or the name and the number, only at the line where mail(correo) match**. Thank you all.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hola "$USER". Este es un script para guardar y actualizar su agenda."
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
if test ! -f agenda.sh
then
    touch agenda.sh
    echo "No tenías una agenda, la creé para ti"
fi
agenda="agenda.sh"
nombre=$1
numero=$2
correo=$3

grep -i "$correo" "$agenda"

if [ $? == 0 ] 
then
    echo "Ya esta registrado con esto correo("$correo")" 
    nom=`grep $correo $agenda | cut -f1 -d ";"`
    telefono=`grep $correo $agenda | cut -f2 -d ";"`
    echo "Datos vecho: $nom $telefono"
    echo "Datos nuevo: $1 $2"
    echo "Quieres sobrescribir los datos?(y/n): "
    read respuesta
    if test $respuesta == "n"
    then
        exit 1
    elif test $respuesta == "y"
    then
        `grep $correo $agenda | cut -f1 -d ";" | sed -i "s/$nom/$1/g" $agenda`
    fi
else
    echo "$nombre;$numero;$correo" >> "$agenda"
    echo "Se ha añadido a la lista."
fi
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH75w.png)

This is the output, but the problem is that in my file the field are these:

marco;rossi;marcorossi

and not these:

marco;rossi;sergiodamico

Do you understand my problem?

Comment: Don't use backticks \` they are deprecated. Use `$( .... )`. Also the line \`grep ...\` will try to execute **the output** of the command, you just want to execute the command not the output of it.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering and modifying columns is the job for awk.

```
newname="$nom"
email="$correo"
file="$agenda"
awk -F ";" '{ OFS=";"; if ($3 == "'"$email"'") $1 = "'"$newname"'"; }1' "$file"
```

- `-F ";"` sets the input field separator as `;`
- `'OFS=";"` sets the output field separator as `;`
- `$3 == "'"$email"'"` check if the third column is equal to $email string
- `$1 = "'"$newname"'"` then it sets the first column to the new name
- `1` non zero value at the end of the script makes awk to print the line

@edit

Och, I am not good in awk and like shell utils, I see two options:

- filter out the line from file with `grep -v -x '[^;]*;[^;];'"$email"` and add that line to it:

```
email_searched=...
IFS=';' read -r _ number _ < <(grep -x '[^;];[^;];'"$email_searched" "$file")
{
   grep -v -x '[^;]*;[^;];'"$email_searched" "$file";
   printf "%s" "$newname;$number;$email_searched"
} | sponge "$file"
```

- You can read the whole file using while read loop and substitute the line (this is the slowest method):

```
while IFS=';' read -r name number email; do
     if [ "$email" = "$email_searched" ]; then
          name="$newname"
     fi
     printf '%s' "$name;$number;$email"
done <"$file" | sponge "$file"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately i have to do this without awk for academic reasons.

Comment: @SergioD'Amico edited the answer

Comment: I have to overwrite the file, i don't understand how printf can make it. I think that the command is sed..??

Comment: I use [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) to overwrite the file as you can't read and write to the same file in the same time (ie. `cat file <file` will truncate the file). if you don't have sponge, use `{ tmp=$(mktemp); cat >"$tmp"; cat "$tmp" >"$file"; rm "$tmp" }` use temporary file in place. Bash allows newline after `|` so maybe it's not visible that I use sponge.